# Link in table cell doesn't work in Mozilla

Tags: php, firefox, hyperlink, html-table

I'm returning a PHP array from a function and want to display in a tabular format with appropriate links in their respective cells. This works fine in IE7 (Windows 7) but the links are not clickable in Firefox 3.5.7. Here is the little bit of code :

```
<td>Monday<?echo "<br>" . $date[1];?></td>

<td><? if($timetable['mon']['1']!=""){ ?>
 <a href="staff_attendance_list.php?pid=mon-1">
   <?  echo $timetable['mon']['1'];} else echo "I";?>
 </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source of the generated page to check that the links *are*, in fact, *links* and not just text?

Comment: In Firefox go to the 'view' menu -> 'page style' -> select 'no style' just to find out whether it's simply a CSS issue (if the link works with CSS disabled it's *just* CSS), or something more complex (though what it could be -apart from CSS- I can't imagine).

Comment: Hey cool you got it right. Its some CSS error. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Webdeveloper plugin for Firefox.  Once you have that installed...

Right click on the cell -> inspect element.  You can view the source and see if an anchor tag is indeed there. If it is and the text isn't clickable or you can't highlight it then you may have a CSS issue.

If that is the case, this is completely an assumption because I don't know what the rest of your layout looks like but it might be that you have a z-index issue and another element (transparent) is blocking the anchor tags from being clickable.  My reasoning behind this assumption is because IE handles z-index's differently and its working in IE.

Comment: Still can't figure out whats the problem.. I'm not using any z index. though using a jQuery menu located sideby the table 8x12 table.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer it was a CSS problem. Figured it out as ricebowl suggested. Thanks a lot to all.